# Запрос к бд по условию - поле даты больше текущей даты

Tags: select

В таблице есть поля `end-time` (дата окончания) и `views` (кол-во просмотров).

Как правильно составить запрос к БД, чтобы выводились самые просматриваемые 3-и статьи, `end-time` которых больше текущей даты? Если `end-time` уже прошел тогда статья не должна учитывается в запросе.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE ?????? ORDER BY `views` DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Дата окончания чего, просмотра, написания статьи? Текущая дата это "за сегодня"?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE DATE(posts.end-time) > CURDATE() ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Запрос работает!